# Infusing with faint stone vs. Infusing with Magic stone?

Tags: dark-souls-2

What exactly is the difference between infusing with a faint stone and infusing with a magic stone?

I seem to understand, that a faint stone will cause a weapon to deal magic damage or a shield to reduce incoming magic damage.
But what does a magic stone do?

The wiki pages left me rather clueless...

Background:
I'm a sorcerer, carrying the Witch Tree branch to cast spells and using a sword in the off-hand for enemies with high magic resistance.
I infused the branch with a faintstone, as was suggested in another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The faint stone adds magic damage scaling with your INT, and the magic stone adds physical damage scaling with your INT. Both reduce other scalings and base damage.
Also the faint stone can be used on shields but not the magic stone.

All else being equal, the magic stone adds less damage than the faint stone but since it's purely physical you don't have to deal with multiple resistances.

Comment: Worth noting that split damage (multiple damage types on one weapon) is much less unfavorable in 2 compared to 1 and 3. Physical damage is (roughly speaking) applied as a flat subtraction (~10% displayed phys. def.), but elemental defense is applied by multiplying by a straight percentage, unlike 1 and 3 where both were subject to flat reductions; this means that e.g. trading 100 physical damage for 100 elemental damage against a 200 mag. def. player only reduces your damage by ~30. Weapon buffs have a percentage multiplier, which more than makes up for the loss.